# Display pop-up message window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

I read about JDialogs and JOptionPane messages but I still can't get it to work. I have a GUI class that extends JFrame. All I want to do is have a popup at the beginning of my program which informs the user about a couple of things. In my main I create the following gui:

```
GUI g = new GUI();
```

Right after that I was to display the window. I have tried the following in the main method:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(g, "work?");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "work?"); //(frame was used in documentation example so I tried it)
```

I also tried to add the pop up into the GUI class with the following

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "work?"); //(I'm not exactly sure what the Frame Owner parameter is supposed to be, unless I'm confusing this with JDialog.)
```

In any case, how would I make this window appear? Every single one of the methods I tried compiled, and nothing happened.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
     private Container background;
     private static buttons etc...
     private static JLabel disp,edisp;
     private static JTextArea info;
     //setting up the GUI for my program, adding action listeners, I can post more if    necessary
}
```

And then I have the main where I want to call the pop up window

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    GUI g = new GUI();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(g,"Work?");
}
```

Comment: JOptionPanes work for me, so I don't know why yours are not working and I suspect your problem is in code not shown us. You should create and post a [minimal runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us what you mean.

Comment: Will do, give me a minute to narrow down the code.

Comment: The "parent" reference relates to a number of uses, 1- to allow the dialog to be "associated" with the parent, visually; 2- Support the modal state of the `JOptionPane`

Comment: I'm sure it works, why would I claim that a feature just doesn't work. I just meant that I did something wrong, and wanted help.

Comment: You will still need to show us what you've done wrong. These snippets above are of no use to us.

Comment: I added what seemed relevant to the problem, the rest of the code is running the program I can post if necessary.

Comment: We don't want snippets and we don't want "the rest of the code". Again as per my first comment, please **create and post a [minimal runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. This program will be at most 40 maybe 60 lines, no more, will run for us and will show your problem to us. If the link doesn't make sense to you, please ask for clarification, but please don't just ignore it.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem while making a minimal runnable example, I'm still not exactly sure what went wrong, but thanks Hovercraft Full of Eels.

Comment: @Howcan: that's not an uncommon occurrence. When you're forced to distill your problem to its most basic form, sometimes the answer will fall out. Good deal and congrats.

Comment: On a side note, I am a bit concerned on your apparent over-use of the `static` modifier in your posted code. Hopefully that's not what your real code looks like, but rather was just sample code for us to look at.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that these are called near the beginning, be it in the main method or not.
Also, try just setting the first parameter as null.
So it reads:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Work?");
```

Also, remember to import it!

Comment: The first parameter specifies the parent component. if `null`, or if the parentComponent has no `Frame`, a default `Frame` is used  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object)

Comment: [6.1 Pop-up Message (Java Code) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_aCZnCJ92E)